# Does the phase-space plot of Lotka-Volterra equations grows chaotically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I find some weird results confusing me in the phase-space plot of Lotka-Volterra equations.
My equation is

$$\frac{d\vec{y}}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{3}y_1 - \frac{4}{3}y_1y_2\\
    -y_2+y_1y_2\\
\end{bmatrix}, \mbox{while}\ \ \vec{y}(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1(t)\\ y_2(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \mbox{and}\ \  \vec{y}(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
From this I get its phase-space plot, which is the curve of the equation 
$$y_1 - \mbox{ln}(y_1) + \frac{4}{3}y_2-\frac{2}{3}\mbox{ln}(y_2)=7/3$$
and this is **a closed curve** which should not expand or shrink.[the curve of $y_1 - \mbox{ln}(y_1) + \frac{4}{3}y_2-\frac{2}{3}\mbox{ln}(y_2)=7/3$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnamA.png)
And it is easy to imagine the 3D curve is **like a coil spring**.

But while I use ode45 in matlab to modify it, I find this curve is not like a closed curve but **a spiral** growing chaotically.
[$y_1,y_2$curve with ode45 in matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yjvW.png)
and the 3D plot is also growing chaotically [3D plot of Lotka-Volterra equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzNpL.png)

It sometimes expands and sometimes shrinks. But in my thought it should **grow in a cylinder**, like a spring.

From the equation $y_1 - \mbox{ln}(y_1) + \frac{4}{3}y_2-\frac{2}{3}\mbox{ln}(y_2)=7/3$ it's totally a closed curve. So is there something wrong with this equation, or the chaos is just the system error of ode45?

Comment: How do you "modify" it? Where does the third dimension come from?

Comment: @Conifold: The third dimension is time (as it says on the axis label).

Comment: How did you invoke `ode45`? For graphically optimal results it should have been via `[T, Y] = ode45(@LV, [0,4000], Y0);`. Optionally use `odeset` to set the absolute and relative tolerances, which might improve the long-term behavior in the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is the result of drawing many large secants inside the convex closed solution curve. To see it happening, I ran the integation on some smaller time intervals, still using the time step 1

[image]

If you go further to `T=4000` as you did, the shift of the secant positions will have covered the full solution curve and result in an image just as you got.

Letting the solver return the internally generated sampling nodes and values instead of prescribing a step size 1 results in the image

[image]

This was produced with python's `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` Using matlab with

```
[T, Y] = ode45(@LV, [0,4000], Y0);
```

will do essentially the same, but insert 3 interpolated points in each segment, so that the plot will follow the curve much more closely.

Another measure is to reduce the step size to `0.1` or smaller. Adding some secants for time steps 1,2,4 to add some content gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I use odeset setting lower tolerances and the curve becomes closed, and the 3d plot grows in a cylinder this time! After setting smaller step size the curve become more smooth as well.

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon is very likely just due to roundoff errors. Going on a closed curve is a very delicate matter, and it's hard to replicate it exactly numerically; if you miss just ever so slightly when coming back to where you started, you will start going in a spiral insted.